# CORS problem when deploying to the server

Tags: .net, angular, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I deployed two projects on the same server. One of them is an angular project and the other is the APIs in.net CORE that the angular project calls.
Locally I didn't have this problem but on the server, every time I call an API, I get this error message in the browser console :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at >'http://myIPAdress:81/Configuration/CODE_CLIENT' from origin >'http://myIPAdress' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control->Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

I deduce that the problem comes from the .NET Core project. I have already tried the proposed solutions on StackoverFlow but without success.
Here is my code on .net Core side :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new 
CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowSpecificOrigin"));
        });
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:80").AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod());
        });

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();
        loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Information);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        // Shows UseCors with named policy.
        app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();


        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

on Angular side, I call my API like this :

```
getConf(code : string){
    var url = "http://MyIPAdress/Configuration";
    return this.http.get<any>(url +'/'+ code)
}
```

locally, I access the data by my API, but not on the server, does anyone know why?

Sorry for my english and for my code I start the programming

EDIT : I added an HTTP response: Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the server's IIS. Now I do not have the same error, but this one:

> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is >'' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The >credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by >the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Try `builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://myIPAdress").AllowAnyHeader()`

Comment: @David always the same problem... I don't understand, my angular call is it good?

Comment: Are you sure the angular side on server call directly the net-core api? Maybe there is a proxy between them?

Comment: Try moving the call `app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");` to just before `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();` so that it's after the call to `app.UseAuthentication();`

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori No proxy between them :/

Comment: @3dd I do not have the same error message anymore, I edited my post

Comment: @CodIng59 after your update, have you checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2#credentials-in-cross-origin-requests)

Comment: @CodIng59 please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

In `builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:80").AllowAnyHeader()`, along with `http://localhost:80` add server IP Address too

Like this:

```
builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:80","http://serverIPAddress.com");
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still the same problem, another idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try with out providing any policy as below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      services.AddCors();
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {

            option.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                .AllowAnyHeader()
                                .AllowAnyMethod();

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the initial error move the 'app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");' to before 'app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();' so that it reads

```
app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

The error you received after that is fixed by adding `AllowCredentials();`, so the CORS entry should be

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
            builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:80").AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials()
        );
    });
```

Comment: Ok thanks, the problems are solved. I no longer have 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' errors but now only: 'GET http: // MyIPAdress: 81 / Configuration / All 500 (Internal Server Error).    When I call this API in POSTMAN or directly in a new tab of the browser, I get a correct JSON file but not in the application

Comment: That could be anything else, you'll need to trace the problem